# 100% horizontal nav menu

Tags: nav

I have tried using:

```
.main-navigation ul {display:table; width:100%;} 
.main-navigation li {display:table-cell;}
```

on my site: http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/ which uses WordPress.

When I make these changes to the site the menu doesn't stretch.
When I change the li to table-cell it removes the block styling on the sub-menus.

Are there any suggestions to help me get my nav menu to stretch accoss the entire width of the site?

I have reverted back to my original padding on the link for now.

Thanks in advance!
Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu-main-navigation { display: table !important; }
#menu-main-navigation ul { display: table-cell; }
#menu-main-navigation a { display: block; text-align: center; }
```

I just applied this CSS to your website and it worked fine for me